# Return list as concatenated string

Tags: freemarker

I have input data as  `test="122 drshshs 000 dkkdkdk 200"`

```
<#list test?split(" ") as curr>
${curr}
</#list>
```

In o/p i m getting output as  :

```
122
drshshs
000
dkkdkdk
200
```

Is there any freemarker short hand function that can directly string give o/p as below instead of looping and adding each string to a variable:

```
122,drshshs,000,dkkdkdk,200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string and then join it with a comma:

```
${test?split(" ")?join(",")}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Also wanted to know if the input contains inconsistent spaces  (eg more than 1 space between words ).   Is there a function to normalize the spaces to 1.so that i can split correctly based on 1 space?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [`?replace`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace) the space with a comma like this:

```
"122 drshshs 000 dkkdkdk 200"?replace(" ", ",")
```

See also:

- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html